# Make a function have the `__name__` of the variable I'm assigning it to

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following function "factory"

```py
def mk_summer(summand=0):
    def summer(x):
        return x + summand
    return summer

foo = mk_summer(summand=42)
assert foo.__name__ == 'summer'  # but I want it to be called "foo"
```

I'd the function to have the name of the variable I'm assigning it to (here `foo`). Of course I could do this:

```py
def mk_summer(summand=0, name=None):
    def summer(x):
        return x + summand
    summer.__name__ = name or summer.__name__
    return summer

foo = mk_summer(summand=42, name='foo')  # Not DRY: 
assert foo.__name__ == 'foo'  # works
```

But that's not D.R.Y.: I need to repeat foo in two places!

Is there some python introspection magic that might allow me to have the `foo = mk_summer(summand=42)` interface, but get the function created to bare the name of the variable I'm assigning it to?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What problem is this a solution to?

Comment: this code looks way too clever -- you're trying too hard to be DRY

Comment: You'll find that the standard library takes the approach of just passing the name in explicitly. For example, [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) takes the type variable's name explicitly. What you're trying to do is fundamentally extremely flaky, failing in any use case that doesn't look exactly like the one very narrow usage you envision.

Comment: This would require introspecting the source code dynamically, which is possible with `inspect` but adds a lot of  needless complexity to avoid rather minimal violation of DRY. Indeed, several parts of the standard library already just pass in the name, e.g. `collections.namedtuple`

Comment: The fact that the standard library (example `type`) does it just means that indeed, the authors didn't see the need. But that doesn't mean some contexts don't call for it, or all languages would be offer the same conveniences.

Comment: @ScottHunter, the problem is reusing as much information about a function as I can to perform static analysis, validation, and decorating to reuse functionality. This obviously requires introspection. Imagine `mk_summer` is used several times in some code, but assigned to different variables. The different functions are distinguished in the code's namespace, but not from the point of view of `__name__`, which can be a problem (in my context).

Comment: Back in ancient times, the brilliant Perl author Mark Jason Dominus wrote a set of [classic](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) [Usenet](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) [posts](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html) with some relevance to your misguided goal. Bottom line: trying to align your variable names and your data values is a bad idea. There are better ways to solve your real problem and keep your code DRY.

Comment: It'd be gross, but you could have `mk_summer` take `locals()` or `globals()` as an argument and then set the name in that...

Comment: @FMc: Wishing for a particular interface can hardly be misguided -- especially if the resulting code is more concise and adapted to a particular problem. Perhaps the more correct, less ignorant, and more respectful answer might have been "these particular languages didn't have that class of use cases in mind when they were designed".

Comment: I strongly disagree that "wishing for a particular interface can hardly be misguided" if it's because the asker can't think of or doesn't know of a better way to solve the problem, or does consider all the side-effects. This could also be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @martineau: I completely get the XY problem, and fall into the confusing the means and the ends trap regularly. In my current line of research though, the means IS the end. Most (dismissive) answers I get here seem to be of "adapt your thought to (the rules of the) code". I'm exploring the possibilities of adapting (the way we code) to the (many) way(s) one can think. Here, the interface is the point of departure; the constraint. The question is then "what is an (elegant) way to do this in the existing language", not "should we be doing it this way?".

Comment: And to all here. I have a genuine question. Why is `__set_name__` ([pep 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/))  okay on a class, but something similar be such an outrage on a module?

Answer (score 1):

As various commenters have tried to suggest, trying to align variable names (the literal code typed by a programmer) and data values (in this case, the functions and their names) is usually a signal that you should think about the problem differently, because it comingles two realms that are fundamentally quite distinct.

I don't know why you are seeking this alignment, but I assume it might be because you intend to create multiple summer functions and therefore want their names to agree with the way that you refer to them in code. In that case, a different approach is to store the functions in a `dict`, keyed by their names.

```
def mk_summer(summand = 0, name = 'summer'):
    # Here we build a real Python function with the desired name, rather than
    # using the half-measure of just setting the function's __name__ attribute.
    code = 'def {}(x):\n    return x + {}'.format(name, summand)
    eval(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
    return locals()[name]

# Three function names. DRY like the Sahara.
NAMES = ('foo', 'bar', 'fubb')

# Create the functions.
funcs = {
    name : mk_summer(summand = i, name = name)
    for i, name in enumerate(NAMES)
}

# Sanity check.
FMT = 'name = {}, __name__ = {}, f(100) {}'
for name, f in funcs.items():
    msg = FMT.format(name, f.__name__, f(100))
    print(msg)

# Note that when we refer to the functions in our code, the agreement
# you seek will exist -- but in the form of a dict key (data, not code).
print(funcs['fubb'](1000))
```

Output:

```
name = foo, __name__ = foo, f(100) 100
name = bar, __name__ = bar, f(100) 101
name = fubb, __name__ = fubb, f(100) 102
1002
```

Comment: Thanks @FMc. I came up with something along those lines too, but it just seemed to hacky. I was hoping for a solution of the sort "oh, yes, there's a dunder for that!". But I'm upvoting because I (really!) appreciate the "hm, let me solve this puzzle" attitude, versus the dismissive ones that seem to be the norm here.

Comment: @thorwhalen Sounds good. If my initial comment here appeared dismissive, that was not my intent and I apologize. Rather, the thing it sounded like you were doing has been a classic request in various user help forums over the decades and almost always involved some sort of XY problem or other misunderstanding -- but one never knows for sure. Also, I'm a fan of Mark Jason Dominus as a programming educator and jump on most chances to promote his work -- I learned a tremendous amount from his writing over the years.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to invent your own [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).
The [m4](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m4) preprocessor makes that very easy,
it's just a `define` away.
You'd probably want a Makefile rule for `%.py: %.m4`

```
        m4  < $<  > $@
```

so that new edits quickly show up in python land.

---

@jamesdlin suggests you could munge the module-level namespace,
and I agree with him that that would not be a clean approach.

But if you did this at `class` level it would look better,
would be easier to document.

Just have the caller invoke `obj.mk_summer(summand=42, name='foo')`,
and your documentation explains to him that a `foo` attribute
shall be added to `obj`,
as a side effect,
in addition to the summer being `return`ed.
(Or have the class maintain a singleton `dict`,
or add it as a class attribute, if that's what you really want.)

Answer (score 0):

i still don't understand *why* anyone would want to do this, but here's a way using decorators that doesn't involve repeating the function name:

```
In [27]: from functools import wraps

In [28]: def mk_summer(summand=0):
       :     def deco(func):
       :         @wraps(func)
       :         def summer(x):
       :             return x + summand
       :         return summer
       :     return deco
       :
       :

In [29]: @mk_summer(4)
       : def foo(x): pass

In [30]: foo(3)
Out[30]: 7

In [31]: foo.__name__
Out[31]: 'foo'
```